# Нужно пустить функцию onchange в цикл Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  let divka = document.createElement('div');
  let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.classList.add('inputtt');
  divka.append(checkbox, `${add.value}`);
  add.value = '';
  document.createElement('div');
  divka.classList.add('inputtt1');
  f1.append(divka);
  f1.onchange = function(e) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      divka.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  color: brown;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 80px auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 450px;
  display: flex;
}

#f1 input {
  float: left;
}

#f1 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.listOne,
.listTwo {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}

.listTwo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="listOne">
      <h2>Task list</h2>
      <form id="f1">

      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="listTwo">
      <h2>Add task</h2>
      <input type="text" id="add">
      <button id="btn" value="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Ребят, помогите, я в Js не долго, и не понимаю в чем проблема: получается так, что я генерирую много checkbox но могу удалить только один из них при нажатии, остальные просто выделяются, а нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог удалять их в любых количествах

Comment: вообще не понятно как они должни ужаляться

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych там есть функция onchange, в ней прописано, что при нажатии на checkbox он должен пропадать. Скопируй код, посмотри

Comment: окей, а зачем тогда ончейндж на форме ? (подсказка, может его на чекбокс повесить ? )))

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych по другому не пашет